# How to plot any 7 point shape in 2D i.e. star

Tags: graphics

I am new to *Mathematica* and I was wondering if anyone knew how to just plot simple shapes with at least 7 points minimum in 2D. What are the required steps I would need to start this? I believe I have to use a system of equations perhaps?

Comment: That's sorta kinda vague. You don't have any other requirements?

Comment: Have you tried [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html)?

Answer (score 7):

For example

```
SeedRandom[Exp[I Pi]];
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {7, 2}];
Framed@Graphics@Polygon@pts[[Last@FindShortestTour@pts]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For a star:

```
s = Transpose@Through[{Re, Im}[E^(2 I Pi Range@7/7)]];
Graphics@Line@Join[s, s, s, s][[1 ;; -1 ;; 3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ss@n_ := Transpose@Through[{Re, Im}[E^(2 I Pi Range@n/n)]];
star@n_ := Graphics[Line[(Join@@ConstantArray[ss@n,Ceiling[n/2]])[[1;;-1;; Floor[n/2]]]]]
star /@ Range[5, 23, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 2}, {1, 2}, {0, 1}};
Graphics[JoinedCurve[Line[points], CurveClosed -> True]]
```

[image: lines]

Here the list `points` has 7 elements, and the `Graphics` contains seven lines connecting these points in the order given. The seventh line is the
one that closes the curve by going from the last to the first point. This is automatically added by specifying the option `CurveClosed` in [`JoinedCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/JoinedCurve.html).

Comment: It's *seven* lines. Count 'em :-)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Counting was never my strong suit... My mothers agree.